# how to access user_friends list Facebook Graph Api v2.0 me/friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

list of my friends with access token without making any app in Facebook .
i used the new Facebook sdk but showing `No node specified` so how to access my friends list. 
i already given permission request user_friends.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

> Friend list now only returns friends who also use your app: The list of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app.